# supersymmetry in 2,6,10 dimension

Tags: supersymmetry, supergravity

Why the susy has chirality in above (2,6,10) dimension?

What i am saying is that for $2, 6, 10$ dimension we can write as follows

For 2d : $N=(16,16), \cdots N=(2,2), N=(2,0), N=(1,1), N=(1,0)$ are possible

For 6d : $N=(2,2), N=(1,1), N=(2,0), N=(1,0)$ are possible.

For 10d: $ N=(1,1), N=(2,0), N=(1,0)$ is possible.

First i realize the special condition for even dimension, but $4d$, $8d$ case we use $N=1$, $N=2$, not $N=(1,0)$ notation.

First guess for this answer was 
known fact for even dimension : where there is no chiral/gauge anomaly.
But since $4d$ and $8d$ are even dimension too, this is not good explanation.

Can you give me some reliable explanation?

Comment: If you look at the possible spinor representations in the respective dimensions, this is the pattern you find (it's a mod 8 pattern, really).

Comment: @ACuriousMind, Thanks! Its related with spinor representation !